# How to simplify this summation?

Tags: summation

I am working through an example in my book, and I can't seem to figure out how they go from one step to another in a particular case. Here is the example: (note: lg here is just the base-2 logarithm, so $\log_{2}n$ is $lgn$)

In the book they go from this step:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{lg n-1}\frac{n}{lgn-i}$$

To this:

$$n\sum_{i=1}^{lg n}\frac{1}{i}$$

I imagine this is some specific way of solving this kind of summation, but I am completely lost.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a change of variable: $i$ is replaced everywhere by $\lg n-i$.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{i=lg n-1}\frac{n}{lgn-i}$$
becomes
$$\sum_{(\lg n-i)=0}^{(\lg n-i)=lg n-1}\frac{n}{\lg n-(\lg n-i)}=\sum_{i=\lg n}^{i=1}\frac ni.$$

---

The sums of the inverse of the first integers are known as the Harmonic numbers. They can be approximated as
$$H_n=\sum_1^n\frac1i\approx\ln n+0.577215\cdots$$

You can observe the similarity with $$\int\frac{dx}x=\ln x+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a sketch and you can fill in the details.  First, you factor out $n$ (which I assume you are fine with).  Now the sums

$$\sum_{i=0}^{lg \;n-1}\frac{1}{lg \;n-i}$$

and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{lg \;n}\frac{1}{i}$$

are actually the same; the terms just appear in the opposite order in the second one.  Try writing out the sums in the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$$

to see this.

Answer (score 1):

$\log_2(n)$ doesn't really make sense as the stopping point of your sum, unless you are only considering $n=2^k$ for some $k>0$. Otherwise $\log_2(n)$ will not be an integer. If $n=2^k$ then $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2(2^k)-1}\frac{2^k}{\log_2(2^k)-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{2^k}{k-i} \\ = 2^k  \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{k-i} \\ = 2^k\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k-2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{k-(k-2)}+\frac{1}{k-(k-1)}\right) \\ = 2^k\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k-2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1}\right) \\ =2^k\left(\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{k-2}+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k}\right) \\ = 2^k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i}  $$

Comment: In the book I got this example from, they find this summation from a recursion tree.